# Java refactoring code smells

Tags: java, coding-style, refactoring

I was given feedback that I need to improve my refactoring/eleminating code smells skills.

1. I need short exercises to detect and how-to improve the most comon code smells 
   **with answers** in java
2. example:

   ```
   public class Calculator {

       public long sum(int min, int max) {
           long result = 0;
           for (int i = min ; i <= max ; i++)
               result += i;
           return result;
       }

       public long sumOfSquares(int min, int max) {
           long result = 0;
           for (int i = min ; i <= max ; i++)
               result += i * i;
           return result;
       }

   }
   ```

and then the best/most convinent solution.
BTW, you could right away show me best solution for this repetition over there /\ maybe with use of operator lambda "->"

Thanks!

Comment: start with separating common and non-common code.

Comment: BTW `->` is not *alpha*, but *lambda* :)

Comment: Of course it's valid, but repetition just hurts eyes, both methods are almost identical

Comment: In my (junior) opinion: 1) adding integers to longs? 2) no braces at your for loop. But I wouldn't call them code smells. Oh dear, of course: repetition

Comment: Relevant books: [Effective Java](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683), [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try *merging* both methods in one. Since both of them look like

```
public long sum(long min, long max) {
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = min ; i <= max ; i++)
        result += someOperation(i);
    return result;
}
```

you could allow user to provide some operation which will compute `i`, so it can be `i` or `i+2` or `i*i`.

Such strategy can be implementation of `LongUnaryOperator` interface where user will need to implement `long applyAsLong(long operand)` method.

So instead of two methods you can have one which can look like

```
public static long sum(long min, long max, LongUnaryOperator mapper) {
    long result = 0;
    for (long i = min ; i <= max ; i++)
        result += mapper.applyAsLong(i);
    return result;
}
```

and you could use it like

```
sum(1, 4, i -> i * i)//sum of squares
```

`i->i*i` is lambda expression which implements functional interface `LongUnaryOperator` and provides implementation of its abstract `applyAsLong` method which will be used in our code. In other words it will map `i` to `i*i`.

more usage examples:

```
sum(1, 4, i -> 2 * i)//sum of doubled values
sum(1, 4, i -> i)//sum of original values
//i->i can be also returned with `LongUnaryOperator.identity()`
//so you can rewrite your code into something like 
sum(1, 4, LongUnaryOperator.identity())
```

You can also rewrite your code using streams like

```
public static long sum(long min, long max, LongUnaryOperator mapper) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(min, max).map(mapper).sum();
}
```